# Kafka message handling in consumer

Tags: java, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

I have a consumer which reads data from a topic and spawns a thread for processing. At a single point of time there can be multiple messages being processed in the server. The application encountered DB timeouts and all the messages being processed were lost. And since there were multiple threads polling for DB connection, the application threw out of memory exception and went down.
How can I improve the architecture to remove data loss even if consumer goes down without processing

Comment: Worth noting that if at all possible it is far simpler to avoid spawning threads to process messages. Better to scale by adding additional consumers (threads or separate processes) to the group and processing in the polling thread, then you can safely commit after each poll completes (or just allow autocommit, which commits previous records during a subsequent poll)

Answer (score 1):

You should do At-Least-Once processing by committing the offsets after you complete your processing.
i.e Do

```
  consumer.commitSync();
```

After your the thread completes successfully.

Note that you also need to configure the consumer to stop commmiting the offset automatically by setting ‘enable.auto.commit’ to false.

You need to be careful though that your consumer is Idempotent. i.e If it fails, and reads and processes the same value again, it will not effect the outcome.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, What would be the solution to following scenario: 2 messages received X and Y. Y is received after X. Processing of X fails whereas Y is successful. Now if I commit offset of Y, X will get committed too.

Comment: Agree with @Chris. Parrellism is achieved in Kafka by adding more consumers to your consumer group. Also note by by spawning threads, you loose the ordering guarantees that Kafka provides as well.

Answer (score 1):

You should commit the offset after getting a successful response from DB.

The issue is related to the available database connection and thread. The only way to handle this issue is to get a database connection and then send the database connection to the thread.

Thread Example

```
public class ConsumerThreadHandler implements Callable {

    private ConsumerRecord consumerRecord;
    private Connection dataBaseConnection;

    public ConsumerThreadHandler(ConsumerRecord consumerRecord,) {
        this.consumerRecord = consumerRecord;
        this.dataBaseConnection = dataBaseConnection;
    }

    @Override
    public Object call() throws Exception {
        // Perform all the data base related things
        // and generate the proper response
        return;
    }
}
```

Consumer Code

```
 executor = new ThreadPoolExecutor(numberOfThreads, numberOfThreads, 0L, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS,
                new LinkedBlockingQueue<>(), new ThreadPoolExecutor.CallerRunsPolicy());

            while (true) {
              ConsumerRecords<String, String> records = consumer.poll(100);
              for (final ConsumerRecord record : records) {
                 // Get database connection , Check untill get the connection  or maintain the connection pool and based on available connection move next.
                Future future=executor.submit(new ConsumerThreadHandler(record,dataBaseConnection));
                if(future.isDone())
                    // Based on the proper response commit the offset
              }
            }
          }
```

You can go through the following simple example.

https://howtoprogram.xyz/2016/05/29/create-multi-threaded-apache-kafka-consumer/

Comment: Thanks for your answer, What would be the solution to following scenario: 2 messages received X and Y. Y is received after X. Processing of X fails for any reason(not just DB) whereas Y is successful. Now if I commit offset of Y, X will get committed too.